# How use multiples properties on "expand" parameter in List component [sapui]

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a [sap.m.List](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.List.html) component where invoke a list of OData objects. This object have others object inside it. For this reason, I use expand parameter for accessing to propertis of intern object. But when I put multiples objects on "expand" parameter, list component doesn't work:

This way doesn't work:

```
<List id="lstRequest" headerText="Custom Content"  
      items="{
                path: '/Requests',
                parameters: {
                   expand: ['RequestTypeDetails', 'UsersDetails']
                }
              }" 
>
    <StandardListItem
        title="{RequestTypeDetails/RequestType2} - {RequestCode}"
        description="{TotalAdvance}"
        icon="sap-icon://request"
        iconDensityAware="false"
        iconInset="false"
        type="Navigation"
        press="onSelectApprovation"  />
</List>
```

This way works:

```
<List id="lstRequest" headerText="Custom Content"  
      items="{
                path: '/Requests',
                parameters: {
                   expand: 'RequestTypeDetails'
                }
              }" 
>
    <StandardListItem
        title="{RequestTypeDetails/RequestType2} - {RequestCode}"
        description="{TotalAdvance}"
        icon="sap-icon://request"
        iconDensityAware="false"
        iconInset="false"
        type="Navigation"
        press="onSelectApprovation"  />
</List>
```

I don't know how especific when I need to use multiples objets on "expand" parameter.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE 1**

The solution give for @Nabi looks working...But I'm not secure because I call elements of list on a detail page.

I create a JSONModel object with element of list and then invoke this object on detail page:

```
var itemJSONModel = new JSONModel(itemObject, false);

this.setModel(itemJSONModel, "detailView");
```

But in my detail page I can't see value of UsersDetails properties (Users is an object inside item object. UsersDeails is the name of NavigationProperty):

```
<Input fieldGroupIds="datos_suscripcion" value="{detailView>/UsersDetails/UserName}"
                       placeholder="Usuario..." 
                       id="inUsuario"/>
```

**EDIT 2**

This is OData model of item object:

```
<EntityType Name="Request">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="AirTicketBuyer" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="AirTicketBuyerEmail" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="BusTicketBuyer" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="BusTicketBuyerEmail" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="CostCenter" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Currency" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Department" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="DepartureDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="DepartureRoute" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
<Property Name="DepartureTransportationType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Destination" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="128"/>
<Property Name="DestinationType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="ExpirationDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="IdApplicant" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="IdCompany" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="IdUser" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Reason" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="200"/>
<Property Name="RequestCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15"/>
<Property Name="RequestFatherId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="RequestStatus" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="RequestType" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="ReturnDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="ReturnRoute" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
<Property Name="ReturnTransportationType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="SapCodeApplicant" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="6"/>
<Property Name="SapCodeUser" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="6"/>
<Property Name="StartFlowDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="TipoReq" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="2"/>
<Property Name="TotalAdvance" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="12" Scale="2"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="ApprovalsRequestDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ApprovalsRequest_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="ApprovalsRequest"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="CostCenterDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Request_CostCenter_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="CostCenter"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="CurrencyDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Currency_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Currency"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="DepartmentDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Department_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Department"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="ExpenseAdvanceDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ExpenseAdvance_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="ExpenseAdvance"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="CompanyDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Company_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Company"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="UsersDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Users_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Users"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="PassengerDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Passenger_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Passenger"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="ReportDocumentDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ReportDocument_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="ReportDocument"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="RequestStatusDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Request_RequestStatus_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="RequestStatus"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="RequestTypeDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.RequestType_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="RequestType"/>
</EntityType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple comma separated string:

```
<List 
    id="lstRequest"
    headerText="Custom Content"  
    items="{
        path: '/Requests',
        parameters: {
            expand: 'RequestTypeDetails,UsersDetails'
        }
    }" 
>
```

Comment: could you post a link where there is documenacion about that?

Comment: I'm not secure if your solution works. I can't see UserDetails object on my detail page. I've updated my question.

Comment: To see if it works you have to check the requests going over the wire for example by using the chrome dev tools. You should see the ODataModel has added the corresponding $expand. You are using OData, aren't you?

Comment: I've posted OData model of item object. I've verified that property of object corresponding to $expand is correct

Comment: Then your initial question was answered. You have changed the subject of your question afterwards. I answered the initial question which was "How use multiples properties on expand parameter in List component". I think you should open another question for the new "content" because it simply does not match the question anymore. Other than that you don't need an additional JSONModel + I suggest you to load the expanded data only at the time when you really need it (which seems to be in your detail page). But again, all this goes too far, it's a different question.

Comment: Well. I ve comprobed that Users object is in y request. For that solution works. Thanks