# How display a OData object which is inside on another OData object on xml view ? [sapui]

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have this OData model:

```
<EntityType Name="Request">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="AirTicketBuyer" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="AirTicketBuyerEmail" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="BusTicketBuyer" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="BusTicketBuyerEmail" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="CostCenter" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Currency" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Department" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="DepartureDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="DepartureRoute" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
<Property Name="DepartureTransportationType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Destination" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="128"/>
<Property Name="DestinationType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="ExpirationDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="IdApplicant" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="IdCompany" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="IdUser" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Reason" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="200"/>
<Property Name="RequestCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="15"/>
<Property Name="RequestFatherId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="RequestStatus" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="RequestType" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="ReturnDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="ReturnRoute" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
<Property Name="ReturnTransportationType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="SapCodeApplicant" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="6"/>
<Property Name="SapCodeUser" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="6"/>
<Property Name="StartFlowDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="TipoReq" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="2"/>
<Property Name="TotalAdvance" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="12" Scale="2"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="ApprovalsRequestDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ApprovalsRequest_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="ApprovalsRequest"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="CostCenterDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Request_CostCenter_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="CostCenter"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="CurrencyDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Currency_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Currency"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="DepartmentDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Department_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Department"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="ExpenseAdvanceDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ExpenseAdvance_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="ExpenseAdvance"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="CompanyDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Company_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Company"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="UsersDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Users_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Users"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="PassengerDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Passenger_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="Passenger"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="ReportDocumentDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ReportDocument_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="ReportDocument"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="RequestStatusDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.Request_RequestStatus_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="RequestStatus"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="RequestTypeDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.RequestType_Request_One_Many0" FromRole="Request" ToRole="RequestType"/>
</EntityType>
```

As you can see, tis object have another OData object inside him (Users):

```
<EntityType Name="Users">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Area" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="DocumentType" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="Email" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
<Property Name="ErpId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="ExpirationDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="IdCompany" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="IdNumber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="30"/>
<Property Name="JoinDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Password" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
<Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="UserAlias" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
//Navigations
</EntityType>
```

I have a master-detail page. I have a list of master objects (of Request type) and on detail page where I can see their properties. I can see all properties but except propertie from "Users" object.

First I created an JSONModel object that contains object of "Request" type:

```
var jsonModelObject = new JSONModel(requestObject, false);

this.setModel(jsonModelObject, "detailView");
```

In my detail page I can't see properties from "Users" object.

This works:

```
<Input fieldGroupIds="datos_suscripcion" value="{detailView>/TipoReq}"
                       placeholder="Código..." 
                       id="inTipoReq"/>
```

This doesn't work:

**1st way:**

```
<Input fieldGroupIds="datos_suscripcion" value="{detailView>/UsersDetails>/UserName}"
                       placeholder="Usuario..." 
                       id="inUsuario"/>
```

**2nd way:**

```
<Input fieldGroupIds="datos_suscripcion" value="{detailView/UsersDetails>/UserName}"
                       placeholder="Usuario..." 
                       id="inUsuario"/>
```

Thanks for your responses :).

**UPDATE 1**

@Alan, I'm trying this ways:

First:

```
<VBox items="{path : 'detailView>/',  parameters: {expand: 'UsersDetails'} }">
                <Input fieldGroupIds="datos_suscripcion" value="{UserName}"
                    placeholder="Usuario..." 
                    id="inUsuario"/>
            </VBox>
```

Second:

```
<VBox items="{path : 'detailView>/',  parameters: {expand: 'UsersDetails'} }">
                    <Input fieldGroupIds="datos_suscripcion" value="{detailView>/UsersDetails/UserName}"
                        placeholder="Usuario..." 
                        id="inUsuario"/>
                </VBox>
```

None of them works...Curiosly, Alan's way and my ways do that input appears multiples times in my page when I select master object.

My page is similar to Master-Deail example. My page consists in a list of master objects. When I select master object, his properties show on detail page. I use press event for showing properties on detail page. For that, request is not triggered...[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005806/how-use-multiples-properties-on-expand-parameter-in-list-component-sapui) you can ver mi example with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access straight to the navigation property. You could do a workaround as the following -

```
<VBox items="{path : 'detailView>/',  parameters: {expand: 'UsersDetails'} }">
   <Label text="{destination}"></Label>
   <VBox items={UsersDetails}>
      <Label text="{UserName}"></Label>
   </VBox>
</VBox>
```

I think that the issue is that when you ran the expand, the result will look like this -

```
  {"AirTicketBuyer":"xxxx",
   ..,
   "TotalAdvance";"xxxx",
   "UserDetails": {
      "results":[{
           "UserName": "this is an user name", 
           ...
       }]
   }}
```

Therefore you need two templates for running the binding. If it doesn't work try to add the detailView>/ before each binding.

Comment: could you try using that expand? if it doen't work, open the devtools and check which request is sent to the backend (in network tab)

Comment: I've also updated my answer, please take a look at it. If that works, just replace the Label for Input

Comment: With your new update I get this message error: During a clone operation, a template was found that neither was marked with 'templateShareable:true' nor 'templateShareable:false'. The framework won't destroy the template. This could cause errors (e.g. duplicate IDs) or memory leaks (The template is used in aggregation 'items' of object '__vbox0').For more information, see documentation under 'Aggregation Binding'. -